# How to solve this ElseThrow exception

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
@Override
public CartPojo save(CartPojo cartPojo) throws IOException {
    Cart cart;
    if (cartPojo.getProductid() != null) {
        cart = cartRepo.findById(cartPojo.getProductid().orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Not Found")));
    } else {
        cart = new Cart();
}
```

An error occur in `orElseThrow` and I can't fix it.

Comment: This means that `getProductId()` returns an empty optional. To fix, you have to set a value (or not use `orElseThrow`, but maybe `orElse`/`orElseGet` – but only you know the requirements what would be "correct")

Comment: What error occurs? What is `cartPojo.getProductId()` returning for type?

Comment: If `cartPojo.getProductid()` returns an `Optional`, then it is very unlikely that it can ever return a `null` value. You likely meant `cartPojo.getProductid().isPresent()` instead of `cartPojo.getProductid() != null`.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking `getProductid()` for nullity, however since it (looks like it) returns an `Optional`, you should instead be checking if it is empty.

```java
    if (cartPojo.getProductid().isPresent())
```

as an added bonus, you can use the `Optional` type a little bit more elegantly:

```java
@Override
public CartPojo save(CartPojo cartPojo) throws IOException {
    Cart cart = cartPojo.getProductid()
        .map(cartRepo::findById)
        .orElseGet(Cart::new);
    // ...
}
```

This accomplishes the same thing as your above code, but takes advantage of some of the niceties of the `Optional` type. It gets rid of needing to throw a `RuntimeException` in a scenario that should never happen.